# Multiple For each performance tuning

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to iterate an object which has list inside list and so on. Since this data is huge in size, I want to exit all iterations when the if condition is met.

Since break is not supported in forEach, how can we achieve this? Is there any better solution other than using `forEach` to increase performance? Performance is key criteria here. Can I use streams / parallel streams here?

```
dataList.forEach(data -> data.getList()
    .forEach(data1 -> data1.getList()
        .forEach(data2 ->data2.getList()
           .forEach(data3 ->data3.getList()
              .forEach(data4 -> {
                  if (data4.getSomeData().equals(someData)) {
                    //some logic to populate some object using data1, data2, data3 & data4 fields
                   //I want to exit all the for each iterations if this condition is met. Since this list is very huge in size
                }
            })))));
```

Comment: You can't stop a forEach. Use booleans to skip or move to loops.

Comment: If performance is key here, have you considered trying to restructure your data to be more tightly bound together here?

Comment: I cannot do that, we are consuming that data from an external source. If I do restructure, then it would take more time than finding the data what is needed

Comment: If you want to optimize, I 2ould suggest not using streams. Usually traditional loops are faster.

Comment: Making it work with streams and carrying the outer values is going to make the code close to unreadable. Nested for-each loops will solve the problem of scope and breaking at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this with a lot of flatmapping stages:

```
Optional<YourObject> mappedData = dataList.getList().stream()
    .flatMap(data -> data.getList().stream()
      .flatMap(d1 -> d1.getList().stream()
        .flatMap(d2 -> d2.getList().stream()
          .flatMap(d3 -> d3.getList().stream()
            .flatMap(d4 -> d4.getList().stream()
              .filter(d4.getSomeData().equals(someData))
              .map(d -> mapping(data, d1, d2, d3, d4, d))))))
    ).findFirst();
```

Another way would be using for-each loops in a method to do the short-circuting:

```
private Optional<YourObject> foo(Data data) {
  for (Data d : data.getList()) {
    for (Data1 d1 : d.getList()) {
      for (Data2 d2 : d1.getList()) {
        for (Data3 d3 : d2.getList()) {
          for (Data4 d4 : d3.getList()) {
            if (d4.getSomeData().equals(someData)) {
              return Optinal.of(mapping(data, d1, d2, d3, d4));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

or with a break statement on the most outer loop:

```
Optional<YourObject> yourObject = Optional.empty();
outer: for (Data d : data.getList()) {
  for (Data1 d1 : d.getList()) {
    for (Data2 d2 : d1.getList()) {
      for (Data3 d3 : d2.getList()) {
        for (Data4 d4 : d3.getList()) {
          if (d4.getSomeData().equals(someData)) {
            yourObject = Optional.of(mapping(data, d1, d2, d3, d4));
            break outer;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Flown Thanks for the reply, but which option would give better performance. We would be receiving data like this at least 100 requests per second. performance is critical requirement here to process this type of data

Comment: @Rohit It really depends. Streams are generating overhead, so I would recommend the for-each loop cascade. But why don't you give it a try and see for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Performance is very similar for - **traditional for** and **forEach** operation most of the cases. So you can use traditional for operation in that case. You can now propagate **break** over every loop.

Demo code:

```
boolean killSwitch = false;
for(;i < size && !killSwitch; i++){
   for( ;j < size && !killSwitch; j++){
       for(;k < size && !killSwitch; k++){
            if(condition == true){
                killSwitch = true;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use nested `for(... dataY: dataX.getList())` loops with a break in the innermost loop?

Comment: Ya, I can use traditional for loop, but I was in a impression that using forEach or Streams would boost the performance.

Comment: @ernest_k, we can use that also.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataList.forEach(
                data -> data.forEach(
                    data1 -> data1.forEach(
                            data2 -> data2.stream().
                                    filter(data2.getSomeData().equals(someData)).
                                    findFirst().
                                    ifPresentOrElse(data2.doSomethingMethod()), () -> {
                                //do failed code
                                return 0;
                            })
                    )
        );
```